# Joomla 3 one time article for 1st time login

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, article

I am trying to make a joomla website and want to show an article for users but only the 1st time they log in(welcome page, terms and policy... etc)
I tried to find on google but really nothing comes up with that particular manner.
Any ideas (preferably simple) highly appreciated.

Comment: unfortunately there is no easy way for doing that , you can handle this with plugins in Joomla with help of user groups , if you have enough knowledge to create this , i can explain more for you ;)

Comment: Yes please. I have some knowledge and I know how to deal with user groups and plugins. Could you hint me what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

ok , so create a user group like "First Time" as child of registered group, then assign this group for "New User Registration Group"  , then create a menu for this groups and assign and set correct access for that

**the coding part** : the easiest way is to create another hidden menu and set it for redirect after login in "Login Redirection Page" in mod_login 
then create a plugin in system folder , and create a listener for onAfterInitialise fo example , and check the url in this method , check the url in this method and check its match with "Login Redirection Page" and also user have First Time user group or not ,if have simply redirect him and also remove the First Time group from this user and assign registered user group to this user

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
unsert($user->groups[5]); // the id of "First Time" user group
$user->groups[2] = 2; // set the registered user group for user
$user->save();
```

for better result set "First Time" and "Registered" groups in admin panel and in plugin setting

Comment: That seems pretty decent. Will give it a try and will update you. Thank you!